# NullPointerException when calling a private final variable in a method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, private

I create `private ArrayList<String> values;`. `values` is assigned a value in the `onCreate` method (`final ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();`). Another method `onOptionsItemSelected` tries to use `values`, but then a `NullPointerException` happens.

The whole class is [here](http://code.google.com/p/mcfriendslist/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sandholm/max/MCFriendsList/MCFriendsListActivity.java), sorry if my explanation was hard to understand. The exception occurs on line 55.

```
package org.sandholm.max.MCFriendsList;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MCFriendsListActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listactivity);
        final ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listactivity, values));
                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
        addUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        addUser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        values.add("vurp0");
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
        });
    }
        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), MCFriendsInfoActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("uname", item);
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
    }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle item selection
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                        values.add("vurp0");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            case R.id.item2:
                //showHelp();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
        private Button addUser;
        private ArrayList<String> values;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
}
```

Please tell me if you need more information(although I doubt it) and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 23 values is *declared* as a local variable (different than your instance variable). Instead, change line 66 to `private final ArrayList<String> values;` and line 23 to `values = new ArrayList<String>();`

Java allows local variables and instance variables to have the same name. In this case, it uses the local variable for operations so you get no error in `onCreate` but later the variable is out of scope (and the instance variable still has not been assigned a value).

Comment: Thank you, this is what worked. I guess writing code I assume works and correcting it according to Eclipse's tips doesn't always work... ;)

Answer (score 1):

`values` which you are using at line no. 55  is an instance variable which you have defined its data type at line no. 66(and you are under impression of using line number 23 reference variable) which by default sets to null. So throwing `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two   ArrayList values    .One of them local which is in oncreate metod.Other one is class level and it never assigned a value.Set class level values.

private Button addUser;
        private ArrayList values;
        private ArrayAdapter adapter;

Answer (score 0):

Better to say, make your `ArrayList` a class member. Of course, it's already a class member, instantiate it where it is declared. Replace your line number `66` with the following statement and use it as and when required through out the application.

```
private final ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You're declaring the `ArrayList` twice in your application once as a class member and again as a local variable. In this situation, the local variable enjoys the higher priority than the class member.